# Concatenate datasets that don't share timestamp values

Tags: python, pandas, unix-timestamp

I have two different `csv` files that correspond to a person's HRV (`csv` no1) and their emotions (`csv` no2). The first dataset used UNIX timestamps to capture the HRV values and the other recorded the person's emotions while they were watching themselves every 5 seconds.

Since the emotions are captured every five seconds and the HRV values are captured every second,
I want to iterate through the rows of the HRV values dataset and create a new one (or just a new column, whatever works) that contains the average sum of each set of 5 rows.
*For example the mean value of the first 5 rows corresponds to that emotion, the next 5 rows correspond to that other emotion etc.*

I want to do that so I can eventually be able to link them with each other.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Unfortunately, I am not able to provide an easily-reproduced code snippet since the dataset is not mine to share, however, I can point out with a few screenshots how my datasets look:

This is the dataset with the HRV values:

[image]

And this is the dataset with the emotion values:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good if you could provide data to test even if it is not real.
I create data with the next code:

```
dates = pd.date_range('10-01-2016', periods=50, freq='S')
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': 100 + np.random.randint(-5, 10, 50).cumsum()},index=dates)
df.head()
```

[image]

I think that [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) from pandas could be useful. Review the [Offset aliases](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases) in the documentation.

```
df.resample('5S').mean().head()
```

[image]

Note that in my example the timestamp is the index, also, I use the mean as the value to pass, but I don't really know what you would like to use. After this, you could just merge the data.

Comment: thank you, I did not know how to create sample data, will do, thanks again!

Comment: so I changed my index to match my DateTime column, add the "on" parameter to specify the column inside the resample method, but I noticed that the first DateTime value/index is that of "2019-01-22 01:21:45" while in my original dataset it starts from "2019-01-22 01:21:48". The rest index values are the mean amount per five indexes but still, it starts differently. Any idea what may be the problem?

Comment: oh, no worries! fixed it by adding the origin parameter and specifying exactly when my starting point should be!